# Convergence of Hilbert transform of a converging sequence

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence, cauchy-principal-value

Fix $n$, and consider random variables $x_1, \dots, x_n$ whose joint p.d.f. is $p_n$.

Assume that the empirical distribution of $x_1, \dots,x_n$ converges weakly almost surely to the probability density function function $\rho(x)$. Moreover, suppose that $x$'s are bounded.

Let $\hat{\rho}_n (y) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i =1}^n \delta(y - x_i)$, which is a p.m.f., and is random itself. Then,

$$
\hat{\rho}_n (y) \to \rho(y) \hspace{5pt} \text{weakly, almost surely under $p_n$}
$$

Define the Hilbert transform of $\rho$ as $H[\rho](z) = {\rm PV} \frac{1}{\pi} \int \frac{\rho(x)}{z-x} \, dx$.

How can I show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}\Big[ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n H[\rho](x_i) \Big] = \int H[\rho](x) \rho(x) \, dx$?
where the expectation is w.r.t. to $p_n$.

Comment: I think that if you just make clear that limit just after "i.e.", the conclusion will follow from there, without too much suffering. What does that limit mean?

Comment: The limit  in fact means, that if we denote the empirical distribution of x's by $\hat{mu}_n$, then $\hat{mu}_n \to \mu$ weakly.

Comment: Yeah, but I think you need to unpack that. What is the "empirical distribution"? What is $\hat{\mu}$? I have the feeling that the answer to your question is not hard once all these definition are written down in formulas.

Comment: I have edited a bit. I hope it's clear now.